# RxDataSources collection view cell always uses fade for insert cell animation, can't change to a different animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I am having an issue with cell animations using `RxSwift` on a `UICollectionView`, my simple setup is as follows:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

let dataSource = RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<SectionOfCustomDataAnimated>(
    animationConfiguration: AnimationConfiguration(insertAnimation: .bottom, reloadAnimation: .bottom, deleteAnimation: .bottom),
    configureCell: { dataSource, cv, indexPath, element in
        let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell
        cell.colorView.backgroundColor = element.color
        return cell
    })
```

With the cell and data models like so:

```
struct CustomDataAnimated {
    let id: Int
    let color: UIColor
}

extension CustomDataAnimated: IdentifiableType, Equatable {
    typealias Identity = Int

    var identity: Identity {
        return id
    }
}

struct SectionOfCustomDataAnimated {
    var items: [Item]

    // Need to provide a unique id, only one section in our model
    var identity: Int {
        return 0
    }
}

extension SectionOfCustomDataAnimated: AnimatableSectionModelType {
    typealias Identity = Int
    typealias Item = CustomDataAnimated

    init(original: SectionOfCustomDataAnimated, items: [Item]) {
        self = original
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

I am using a `BehaviourRelay` that updates when the `update` button is pressed:

```
 private let sections = BehaviorRelay<[SectionOfCustomDataAnimated]>(
        value: [SectionOfCustomDataAnimated(items: [
            CustomDataAnimated(id: 0, color: .red),
            CustomDataAnimated(id: 1, color: .yellow)
    ])])

 @IBAction func didTapUpdate(_ sender: Any) {
        let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .blue, .green, .purple, .orange]
        let originalColors = sections.value.first!.items
        self.sections.accept([SectionOfCustomDataAnimated(items: originalColors + [CustomDataAnimated(id: originalColors.count ,color: colors.randomElement()!)])])
    }
```

[image]

The problem is that the collection view *does* animate however it seems it *always* uses a fade style animation. Choosing a different option such as `.bottom` in the example above still results in the same fade animation. I have used similar logic on a table view before and there was no issue, I only seem to have the issue in collection views. How can I get the different style of animations to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UICollectionView` insertion/deletion animations are handled by the layout so the `RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource` cannot do that for you. If you take a look at the `insertRows`/`insertItems` funcs for example, you will notice that for [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) it takes animation while for [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitems) does not. What you are seeing is the default animation used by `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which is a fade animation. If you want a custom behavior you have to create a layout subclass and there are plenty of [tutorials](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/306-customizing-collection-view-cell-insertion-animations) for that.

Comment: Thanks for that. Was assuming I had to do something like that.

Comment: Its not true. RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource can do this. Try to sections.bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource)) in viewDidLoad or same method. And change sections like in your example. And try to use right for example – headstream 7 mins ago    Delete

Comment: @headstream Are you sure you are not using a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`? If you check [this](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/blob/main/Sources/RxDataSources/UI+SectionedViewType.swift#L57) you will notice that animations are not used. Do you have a working example?